# Testing notification between 2 apps

Tags: android-espresso, android-uiautomator

is there any way of UI testing a notification sent between 2 apps with espresso, UIAutomator or other framework?

This would include testing the third party provider.

Any experience?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to test the notifications by taking advantage of my notifications provider infrastructure, https://pushy.me/

- On one hand, I can make a notification from the sender device and verify this notification is stored in Pushy servers by using Pushy SDK (https://pushy.me/docs/api/device).
- On the other hand, I can trigger a notification with Pushy SDK (https://pushy.me/docs/api/send-notifications) and detect it reaches the destination device.

This looks like a test plan.